# How to create a patch which counts empty directories?

Tags: diff, patch

I have the following directories:

```
$ tree
.
├── new
│   └── dir1
└── old
```

I want to create a patch using `diff` and apply it to the `old`.

This one doesn't change the `old`:

```
$ diff -ruN old new | patch -s -p0 -t && tree
.
├── new
│   └── dir1
└── old
```

This one leads to error:

```
$ diff -ru old new | patch -s -p0 -t && tree
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

A simple question: how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need more than `diff` output.

The [manpage](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_patch/blob/817d7d17674b6e85281ed78c82c204d618f028df/patch.man#L1020) for GNU patch states:

> Context diffs cannot reliably represent the  creation  or  deletion  of
> empty  files,  empty  directories,  or  special  files such as symbolic
> links.  Nor can they represent changes to file metadata like ownership,
> permissions, or whether one file is a hard link to another.  If changes
> like these are also  required,  separate  instructions  (e.g.  a  shell
> script) to accomplish them should accompany the patch.

Comment: Extra: 1) Do you know the rationale for "Context diffs cannot reliably represent ..."? What are the obstacles to "reliably represent ..."? 2) Any ideas how to solve the task using "more than diff"?

Comment: 1) Your test code using the normal diff command to create a patch did not create empty directory. QED. 2) A shell script? List empty files: `find old -type f -size 0`. List empty directories: `find old -type d -exec sh -c '[ "$1/*" = "$(echo "$1"/*)" ]' -- {} \; -print`. Then a shell script that does `touch` or `mkdir -p`. If paths can contain odd characters, you'll need to escape them properly. GNU find's `-printf` and `-z` can help for that, if available to you.

Comment: with GNU find/sort/sed: `(cd old; find * -empty -printf '%y%p\0' | sort -zr | sed -zE "/^[fd]/! d; s/'/'\\\''/g; s/$/'\n/; s/^f/touch '/; s/^d/mkdir -p '/") > mkemptypaths`

Comment: `-empty` may be unreliable for testing directories on some filesystems. An approximate equivalent test is: `-type d -exec sh -c '[ "$1/* $1/. $1/.." = "$(echo "$1"/* "$1"/.*)" ]" -- {} \;`